# embed styles in <style> tags, or use <link> tags?

Tags: php, stylesheet

I have a php function that I use to write out my `<link>` tags.

Now I thought about this and,

it would be just as easy to modify the function so it will write out a

```
<style>
//stylesheet contents here
</style>
```

block.

can anyone please tell me why this is/is not a good idea.

So far it seems 1 for 1.

Pro: You have less requests to the server.
Con: The stylesheet will not be cached.

What do you think?

Comment: The pro is not really valid; you will have 1 (if you combine your CSS files) extra request for the first time, but then after that, it is cached; so you will have the same amount of HTTP requests (but using `<style>`, you'll still be carrying all the CSS weight).

Comment: Keeping HTML and CSS files separate sure keeps things much more readable and clear, especially since you can easily have multiple CSS files, many hundreds of lines long each.

Comment: @polarblau: @Hailwood just is asking if he should combine the files for the live server, not development.

Comment: The question is why? you don't gain anything from doing this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reading the css with php might take more processing on the server than just showing the css url in the `<link>` tag (I guess you're using file_get_contents()).